# Codova camera plugin delete images from gallery

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have created an app to capture the images and store it in gallery/photo album, I am able to successfully capture image and show it in the gallery/photo album using the Cordova Camera Plugin by making use of the option

saveToPhotoAlbum: true

But now,When I uninstall the app how do I delete the images which are saved  to the photo album or gallery.

Comment: Way outside the scope of `cordova-plugin-camera`.  Plugin doesn't retain a history of the images taken, plus I'm not familiar with any platform who's apps have hooks that would allow that kind of process.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating folder and store the file in the app internal storage. It will automatically gets deleted.

So for doing this we have the following steps. This is mentioned in [Cordova File plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) documentation.

**On Android**

add one of these two lines to config.xml:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Without this line, the File plugin will use Compatibility as the default. If a preference tag is present, and is not one of these values, the application will not start.

**On iOS**

add one of these two lines to config.xml:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Without this line, the File plugin will use Compatibility as the default. If a preference tag is present, and is not one of these values, the application will not start.